# EXCEL Workbook creating phantom worksheets that can't be deleted

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with some VBA code  in modules and in the worksheets. As I use the workbook, Excel will suddenly create ghost/phantom worksheets that can't be deleted. IN the screen shot below the original works sheets, Sheet17 (Main Menu ) and Sheet 25 (Results) ended up getting duplicated (Sheet17, Sheet171, Sheet1711, Sheet 17111; Sheet25, Sheet251, Sheet2511, Sheet25111, etc). The version less than Sheet17111 are ghost worksheets (notice the different icon) that can not be deleted. The VBA code for those worksheets stayed with the latest version of the worksheet (ie. Sheet17111).

The only way to get rid of the ghost worksheets is to save the workbook as an xlsx, close the workbook open up the xlsx, copy over the worksheet code and modules and save out the xlsm. Of course this only corrects the problem until the next occurrence

I am not calling any special addins.
Any tips on what I can try to correct this problem.
Ian

[image]

Comment: It has to be in the code, of course, but this will be a puzzle to track down. Look for any code in which you're copy/pasting and certainly any `Worksheets.Add` happening. You can also write some code to catch the `NewSheet` [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.newsheet?view=vsto-2017) and look at the call stack to see how it was called.

Comment: As you said it is definitely in the code. Not adding or removing any sheets. The only thing out of the ordinary is that I am accessing the sheets via the sheetID but that is restricted to Sheet23/Sheet24  and Chart1/Chart where I rename worksheet names using the sheetIDs. Will look at adding code to a NewSheet Event to see if that gets me anywhere.

Comment: Is there any possibility that this is caused by another workbook. I can't think of a reason why or how but I have a couple of personal macro files that are used alot  by multiple workbooks.

Comment: It depends on the macros in your Personal.xlsm/xlam. How consistent were you in those personal macros in referencing `ThisWorkbook` or `ActiveWorkbook` or in excluding certain workbooks or activities?  From my (limited) view here, I think writing a newsheet event sub to catch it when it happens should tell you

Comment: That is a good comment. If the xlsm file I try to use ThisWorkbook but in the personal macro files the choice is a little more difficult. But great suggestion none the less

Comment: Still looking at this as a possibility for my phantom sheets but this raises the question as what is the correxct way to refer back to the calling workbook from a personal macro file?

Comment: Here is a [one discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39779724/4717755) on how to make those references, and [here is another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67075888/4717755).

Comment: Appreciate the comments. Unfortunately I am  not making much progress. I added a Workbook_NewSheet macro to just output a msgbox when called and removed all of my personal macros files so no possible conflict there. I am still getting the phantom worksheets. These worksheets are not visible in excel, only in the VBA ide. In the IDE, they can not be deleted.  Also notice that the icon beside the sheet is different. IN the screen cap above, the sheet available in Excel is Sheet17111 (Main Menu). The sheets Sheet17, Sheet171 and Sheet1711 are the phantom worksheets that can not be deleted.

Comment: Moving forward when working with personal macro files I am going to be passing the calling workbook name as a variable

Comment: Here is one more piece of information. The extra phantom worksheets are created when the workbook is saved and reopened. Was running some tests executing all of the various macros. That did not result in the extra worksheets until I saved and reopened the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with this bug, it happens only to specific Excel files.
These abnormal Microsoft Excel Objects appear when one of the specific Excel files are already open, AND that I open another Excel file.
The main practical issue is that all the VBA code that was in the normal Microsoft Excel Object finds itself in the abnormal MEO; in consequence, the ActiveX butins in the sheet won't work anymore.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).